# Elements of nested list

Tags: python

I want to printed every single letter in all elements of a nested list in Python.
For examaple if the list is :

```
my_list=[book,map,[red,pink,[berry,lemon]],pencil]
```

Comment: How is [tag:computer-vision] involved? Is your computer reading your list through a webcam?

Comment: Welcome to SO. So far you have only stated a requirement, but you haven't asked a question. Please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and include your own attempt (the code you have so far) in the question.

Comment: You might have a look at the [official Python tutorial on lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (naturally you can change the print form to do something else with the character) :

```
sequence = ['book','map',['red','pink',['berry','lemon']],'pencil']

def printCharacters(items):
    for x in items:
        if isinstance(x, list): printCharacters(x)
        elif isinstance(x, str):
            for c in x: print(c)

printCharacters(sequence)
```

Comment: In this version they will be ignored, but it would be possible to handle them. What would you want to do with integers ?

Comment: Thank you very much. I figured out what to do if there were numbers in the list thanks to you. 